# How to display my console logs on my tkinter window?

Tags: python, tkinter, tqdm

```
from tkinter import Tk
from tqdm import tqdm
root = Tk()
root.geometry('300x300')
root.mainloop()
for i in tqdm(range(1000)):
    pass
```

Can it see the process bar inside m tkinter window?